# How to train Ultralytics YOLOv8 computer vision model using Apple M1 CPU/GPU using multithreading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, pytorch, computer-vision, yolo

I have faced some problems with training my YOLOv8 computer vision model locally on my laptop.

Laptop characteristics listed below:
MacBook Air

Year of production: 2021

CPU: Apple M1 Silicon with 8 kernels

GPU: MPS with 8 kernels

CPU/GPU-memory: 8GB

If I count total number of kernels I would get 16 as total number of kernels(threads)

Tools which I am using are listed below:

CV model: Ultralytics YOLOv8

Libraries/Modules: PyTorch, NumPy, OpenCV, OS, threading

Language: Python 3.8

Dataset is already divided into train, test and val parts so I'm not gonna use `yolosplitter` to split the dataset.

However I want to split my dataset in case that I can use multiple threads to train my model. My dataset contains 1561 elements in `/train/images` folder and 1561 elements in `/train/labels` folder. I want to divide the training of model using multithreading in Python. I have counted that the most suitable variant for me is to divide the dataset into parts which contains approximately 375 images and annotations per one thread. However, function `train()` inside the YOLO class accepts only data as a single `yaml` file so it looks like that:

```
model.train(data="data.yaml", batch_size=30, epochs=10, device="mps")
```

Such structure doesn't allow me to split a tension on the CPU cause it requires only single `yaml` file.

MY THOUGHTS:

1)I need to create a `map()` where the key is image and the value is annotation

2)Then I need to load into all of 8 threads 375 images and labels into thread

But my plan crashes when I need to begin the process of training. The only way which I have found on myself is to split data into 8 `yaml` files where each of them contain 375 images/labels for 1 thread.

Dataset `yaml` file looks like this:

```
path: ../datasets/roboflow
train: train/images
val: valid/images
test: test/images

names:
  0: Aircraft
  1: Armoured Fighting Vehicle-AFV-
  2: Armoured Personal Carrier-APC-
  3: Army-vehicle
  4: Light Armoured Vehicle-LAV-
  5: Military engineering vehicle-MEV-
```

What can you advise me?

Comment: why are you ignoring me?